# Local user login access in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a created a local user called 'MynetDB' with SQL Server Authentication (password) in SQL server 2008. Server roles is `public` and user mapping to 2 databases as `db_owner` and `public`. Status has `Permission to connect database engine:` = Grant and `Login:` = Enabled.

When I try to connect to server database engine with SQL Server authentication it is giving error `Login failed for user 'MynetDB'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)`

I also tried from C# code giving same error. Please advise me how access the databases?

**Edit:**
I am getting error on Management studio also

C#

```
<remove name="MyNetDB" />
    <add name="MyNetDB" connectionString="Data Source={ServerName};Initial Catalog=MynetDB;User Id=MynetDB;Password=taD6eg4c;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Apart from the user, have you created a login? These are _separate_ things.

Comment: check out this link this may help you to resolve how the user logs in to the Server via Domain or user account as a hint ... http://www.sql-server-business-intelligence.com/sql-server/error-code/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-for-user

Comment: Is the SQL instance set up to use SQL Server logins, or is it in Windows-only mode?

Answer (score 2):

To figure out exactly what is happening, you should check the State that is reported in the message, either in the event log or SQL Server log. For example:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.

The state will usually help narrow down the exact cause. Here is a list of the states and their meanings:

```
Err  Message
 2   Invalid userid 
 5   Invalid userid
 6   Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
 7   Login disabled or password mismatch
 8   Password mismatch
 9   Invalid password
11   Valid login but server access failure
12   Valid login but server access failure
13   SQL Server service paused
18   Change password required
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into SQL Server Mgmt Studio GUI, create the appropriate Windows login, and assign privileges to that Windows user or group, too.

Comment: Not if the OP is using SQL Server authentication (which the OP states in the question).

Comment: @Shark - I got the impression that, by "local user", the OP meant "local Windows user".  If he's using SQL Server authentication, then his MSSQL is running in mixed mode, and he *can* mix Windows and SQL server authentication.  He just needs to understand the difference.  And the difference between securing an "object" (database access) vs. "connecting" (which requires a valid Windows or MSSQL logon, *and* the privilege to access the default database).  He's got several good suggestions so far...

Answer (score 0):

Is the database name `mynetdb`?

Do you have access to the SQL Error log? If so, please post the message, or, if you can access the Windows Event Log on the server, you can post the error for the failed login from there.

This problem could also be because the login defaults to the master database, which the login may not have access to.  When you look at the login properties, what is the default database? Is it master or is it the database you need access to?

It could be one of many possibilities. The complete error message would be more helpful

Comment: It wouldn't matter what the login's default database is because that is only used if no Initial Catalog is specified.  The code posted shows he is setting the Initial Catalog to MyNetDB.  Best bet is to start with the Error State